# How to load local images in React through props?

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-props

I have placed downloaded images in an `images` folder inside my `public` folder. The images are numbered from 1 to 10.

[image: images directory structure]

In my `App.js` file I am passing the `id` of each image to `Component.js`.

```
return(
  <div>
    {info.map((users, i) => {
      return(
        <Component key={i} id={info[i].id} />
      )
    })}
  </div>
)
```

And in the `Component.js` file, I am rendering an image like this:

```
<img alt='image' src='/images/{this.props.id}.jpg'/>
```

My vision is that I will send an id through props from `App.js` and in `Component.js` I will use that id for `{this.props.id}.jpg` to display the id's respective image. The page is loading and there are no errors showing up but I am not able to see the images. I then changed the images folder's location and tried doing this:

```
<img alt='image' src={require(`D:/project-name/src/images/${this.props.id}.jpg`)}/>
```

But still facing the same issue. Please help me solve this issue.

Comment: Looks like in your second code block, you aren't using a template string which would cause all the images to have the same url of `/images/{this.props.id}.jpg`.  That could be your problem.

Comment: @MarkSkelton i tried ' src={ `/images/{this.props.id}.jpg` } ' , but facing the same issue.

Comment: That is very close, but you are also missing a dollar sign before `{this.props`.  Try changing it to `${this.props`

Comment: @MarkSkelton Thank you for your comment!! The images are now visible.

Comment: Great, I just posted that as an answer for others who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in your image tag. Try making the string a template string and don't forget to add the missing dollar sign before `{this.props.id}`.

```js
<img alt='image' src={`/images/${this.props.id}.jpg`} />
```

Comment: Hi, I just tried this and it crashed my site. I put my Images folder in public folder. The pictures there are not named serially like 0,1,2,3. Just random names.
I used:
<img  src={`/Images/${this.props.id}.png`} height='300' alt='robots' />